# How to figure out if a value is in a range of cells using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So far I was able to get the range and using indexOf, but when I try to get the index the value is always -1 even when the value is in the range.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('url');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetName');

var lookUp = "0000";
var lookUpRange = sheet.getRange(2,5,3,1).getValues();
Logger.log(lookUpRange);//this prints the array  [[0000], [123 456 7890], [98765.0]]
//but when I do
var index = lookUpRange.indexOf(lookUp);
Logger.log(index);
//the output I get is -1.0
```

Even when I change the variable lookUp I still get -1.0 as the index. Is there something I'm missing? How can I get a positive number so I can check to see if my array has a specific value?
Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the data types of your array, you're looking for the string `"0000"` whereas the `0000` in your array could be a number, in which case your `indexOf` will not find it.

Answer (score 3):

### Keep in mind that the value range is a 2-D array.

You need to loop through the outer array (rows).

Sample:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('url');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetName');

var lookUp = "0000";
var lookUpRange = sheet.getRange(2,5,3,1).getValues();
Logger.log(lookUpRange);//this prints the array  [[0000], [123 456 7890], [98765.0]]
//but when I do
for (var i = 0; i < lookUpRange.length; i++){
  var index = lookUpRange[i].indexOf(lookUp);
  Logger.log(index);
}
```